# how to add click on pie chart using achartengine

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I have made a pie chart with the help  of achartengine now i want to set click command so that a new view opens when user clicks on the pie chart. a different view for different wedge of pie chart. i tried with iTouchHandler but i donno how to handle touch. i have set the onClickEnabled(true) in renderer but how to i make it listen to my commands please help.. the code is given below..

```
 import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
 import org.achartengine.ITouchHandler;
 import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
 import org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer;
 import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
 import org.achartengine.tools.PanListener;
 import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomListener;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.storage.OnObbStateChangeListener;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

 public class PieChart implements ITouchHandler 
{
public Intent getIntent(Context context) 
{
    double[] values = new double[] {12, 14, 11, 10,2};
    int[] colors = new int[] {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN};
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
    return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, buildCategoryDataset("Project budget", values), renderer,"pie");
  }
protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    renderer.getSelectableBuffer();
    renderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(30);

    for (int color : colors) {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(color);
      r.setDisplayChartValues(false);

      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
  }
protected CategorySeries buildCategoryDataset(String title, double[] values) {
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(title);
    int k = 0;
    for (double value : values) {
      series.add("Project " + ++k, value);
    }

    return series;

}
public void addPanListener(PanListener arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void addZoomListener(ZoomListener arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public boolean handleTouch(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("lskdflk");

    return false;
}
public void removePanListener(PanListener arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void removeZoomListener(ZoomListener arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can add a click listener to a chart **activity**.

But if possible, you may instead create a chart **View** using `getPieChartView()` and call [`setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) on the returned View.